# angular js ng-view functionality

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, ng-view

I have been trying to make ng-view work in a simple example app without success. Could someone perhaps point to me where the code is written wrong?

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/y0oER1SKszkbihq6ESsH?p=preview)

```
<a href="/one">one</a>
<a href="/two">two</a>
```

Is the manner of these lines written the one at fault?

Comment: You're using angular v1.2.0 but angular-route v1.4.4, this may be a first issue.

Comment: @Abbadiah http://plnkr.co/edit/zQZWlOluyavauBydVoWD?p=preview without html5 mode atm, looks like html5mode does not work on plnkr but i am not sure

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/vmqDVQZmRS1jVrugJlhU?p=preview

A couple of issues.

First, use `template` instead of `templateUrl` inside plunkr unless you pre-cache http requests. Plunkr does not allow you to make http requests.

Second, like sp00m said, you have a mismatch of versions. They should all be 1.2.0 or 1.4.4 (or anything else, just as long as they're the same version).

Third, you need `<base href="/">` in your `<head></head>`.

Finally, simple mistake here- `.otherwise({redirectTo: '/one.html'})` needs to be `.otherwise({redirectTo: '/one'})`

Comment: plunker code provided by @sbaaaang works like a charm, the question however is how to receive the same result with html5 mode. Seeing plunker has it's limitations with it, how would it be possible assuming that one uses his own server(like wamp or xampp)?

Comment: This is just at the http layer. You can request the templateUrl through the standard means and avoid the plunkr issue by adding the html to the templateCache first. `$templateCache.put('one.html', 'one');`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

It will work on your http server as long as your http handles requests properly.